# setting up qt creator to work with tortoise svn on windows

Tags: svn, qt, tortoisesvn, qt-creator

I was wondering how one would set up qt creator 2.1.0 to work with tortoise svn on windows 7. I have been using tortoise for quite some time now and would like for it to work. I have tried to find some tutorials online and been unsuccessful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use tortoise directly with Qt. But you can setup Qt to use SilkSvn to work with your tortoise server.
here is the link : [silksvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)

Comment: My svn server is not tortoise. It is running on a linux machine i have. tigris svn, i believe. I use tortoise on my windows machine to interact with my svn repos.

Comment: I think major Svn Client should work. For example, at my work, our server is running a tortoise server but I configured QtCreator to use SlikSvn in the Subversion options (of QtCreator). But when I browse throw windows Explorer I use tortoise.

Comment: Ok, i will give it a try. Will let you know results.

Answer (score 6):

I use QT Creator and Tortoise for testing and playing around with svn.

You have to install Tortoise including the "command line client tools" option.
Open QT Creator, go to Tool / Options / Version Control / SVN. 
Insert "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" to "Subversion Command"

Create a new project (if you have none)

Create an Repository with Tortoise --> https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-quick-start.html

If you want to use your original project folder as local working copy -->
https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html#tsvn-dug-import-in-place

If you have checked out your project once and reopen it the QTCreator, QT Creator will realize that your project has a svn VersionControl. You can see the revision in [] after the name of your project. 
Now you can checkout an update your Repository with QTCreator: Press Tools > Subversion.

*I know - this post is 5 years old. I've been looking for a tutorial how to use tortoise "with" QTCreator for a long time. This is the conclusion of my research. Hope it'll help other newbies having the same problem.*